# How to deploy KinesisAutoscaling.war on Java Application Server or Tomcat?

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat, amazon-ec2, autoscaling, amazon-kinesis

I want to manage kinesis shards automatically so I want to deploy KinesisAutoscaling.war on Tomcat. I found steps(https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-scaling-utils) to deploy at Elastic Beanstalk.

Similar way I want step by step solution to deploy on Tomcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to slow this problem using below steps.

1. Downlaod the [code](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-scaling-utils) from here.
2. Open the project as Maven project in eclipse
3. Change the stream configuration in the `configuration.json` and provide the path of configuration in `AutoscalingController.java` like below

> String configPath = "C:\
>   amazon-kinesis-scaling-utils-master\conf\configuration.json";

4. Build the project and place `.jar` file to the webapps folder of `tomcat` and start tomcat.